# How to get the document ID's from the selected documents in SPFx listView extension?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, spfx, pnp-js

I have a folder with documents and a SharePoint `listView extension`.

I want to be able to retrieve the Document ID's after selecting documents in the folder in order to perform `Graph API` requests with them later on. How do I do that? Currently I have this:

```
private async handleCommand(selectedItems: any[]): Promise<void> {
    try {
      if (selectedItems && selectedItems.length > 0) {
        const results: string[] = [];

        for (const selectedItem of selectedItems) {
          const fileName = selectedItem.getValueByName('FileLeafRef');
          const folderPath = '<path>';

          try {
            const item = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath + fileName).getItem<{
              Id: number,
              Title: string
            }>('Id', 'Title');

            console.log(`Id: ${item.Id} -- ${item.Title}`);

            await item.getCurrentUserEffectivePermissions().then(perms => {
              console.log(perms);
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error getting item for ${fileName}:`, error);
            results.push(`Error getting item for ${fileName}: ${error.message}`);
          }
        }

        // Display the combined results in a single alert
        await Dialog.alert(`Selected documents:\n${results.join('\n')}`);
      } else {
        // No items selected, handle accordingly
        await Dialog.alert('No items selected.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling command:', error);
      await Dialog.alert(`Error handling command: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
```

I tried this code but it gives me a 403 error.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

I used the documentation of https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files but it's not clear to me on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to getting the internal `Id` of the `List Item` you do not have to perform a SharePoint Request.

You can get fetch the `Id` column from the `ReadonlyArray<RowAccessor>` list.

It can be located from the event: `IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters` object.

In the below code of `onExecute` function:

```
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
switch (event.itemId) {
  case 'COMMAND_1':
    console.log(event.selectedRows.map(item => item.getValueByName('ID')));
    console.log(event.selectedRows);
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown command');
   }
}
```

You can see that we can map the `selectedRows` property so that it returns an array of the `IDs` of the selected Items. A screenshot of this can be seen below:

[image: array of Ids of selected Items]

There are also plenty of other properties that are carried alongside the view of the list, some of which are the below:

[image: complete list of item values]

Keep in mind, that if a column is not included in the values or if the `getValueByName` function is returning `null`, you should include the column in the selected View. Also, the repo that you are looking at is deprecated and archived. I would recommend you take a look at the newer versions of the library [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/).